# Dual citizenship. Am I eligible to travel to the US via the Visa Waiver Program

Tags: us-visa-waiver-program, dual-nationality, south-african-citizens, portuguese-citizens

So I'm planning to go to the US in December. I have dual citizenship, South Africa and Portugal. I was looking to travel on my portuguese passport using the visa waiver program. My only issue is I have been into the US on my South African passport previously (most recent being 2003).

Do you think this would be a problem? Previous visas are expired

Comment: Why would it be a problem? Have you previously had issues with US immigration?

Comment: Nope. We're just going on holiday to visit family. We just weren't sure if they would query why we've been on before on a SA passport and why the change. I have no idea if they would have record of that? Also my boyfriend will be travelling in on a SA passport with us

Comment: The [ESTA form](https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/esta/) you'll need to fill out before your trip will likely ask you if you are a citizen of any other country. Just answer honestly.

Answer (score 8):

Unless you've previously been refused a US visa or otherwise had issues with US immigration, it's perfectly okay to travel on your Portuguese passport. Millions of people with dual citizenship travel to the US each year so the border guards won't be surprised with your new citizenship.

Relax and enjoy your stay in the US.

Comment: Thanks everyone! Just wanted to triple check everything :) I appreciate the answers

Comment: They might ask you *why* you have Portuguese citizenship.